# Chrome autofill not picked up by regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am doing some server-side checks using ASP.NET C#. I have spotted an error within the system when debugging, here is my code:

```
Regex validEmail = new Regex("/^\\S+@\\S+\\.\\S+$/");

   if (!validEmail.IsMatch(email_txt.Text))
      {
            email_lbl.Text = "You must enter a valid email address";
            email_lbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            email_txt.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            email_txt.BorderStyle = System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.Solid;
      }
      else
      {

      }
```

This is within my button Click event.

The issue is, when I autofill the form by selecting an email address from the dropdown list of the textbox supplied by Google Chromes AutoFill "liverpool@live.com" it falls into the IF statement rather than the ELSE statement.

However, if I manually fill out the email address the exact same it will fall into the ELSE statement.

Does anyone know the problem as to why this is happening?

Comment: Don't try to validate email with a regex.  You'll erroneously mark far too many valid emails as "invalid". http://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No delimiters are allowed in C# regex pattern.

Use `new Regex(@"^\S+@\S+\.\S+$")`.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5CS%2B%40%5CS%2B%5C.%5CS%2B%24&i=liverpool%40live.com)

[Sample code](http://ideone.com/03lBKC):

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^\S+@\S+\.\S+$");
Console.WriteLine(rx.IsMatch("liverpool@live.com"));
```

Note that `@""` is a verbatim string literal that is the most convenient notation to use when writing C# regex patterns. You do not have to escape anything, only double `"` (as `""`) to match just one `"`.

Comment: Perfect! I also have these regex's what should I do with these, "/^\\S*$/" and "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$"

Comment: Just remove the leading/trailing ``/``s, and use `@"..."` notation if there is anything to escape in the pattern: `@"^\S*$"` and `"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$"`.

Comment: Should I also remove the trailing /'s in JavaScript?

Comment: In JavaScript literal regex notation, you *must* use the delimiters. I have just thought about the regex: `\S` also matches a literal `.`. So, you just require at least 1 `.` in the part after `@`, right? I hope you are OK with it and know what you are doing. Just occurred to me after reading Brian's comment.